# How to write to the _default stream of a BigQuery table using the Write Storage API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I would like to use the BigQuery Write Storage API to stream single rows of data into a table. However, I do not want to create new write streams for each row.

[According to the docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerystorage/latest/bigquery_storage_v1/library.html#google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1.client.BigQueryWriteClient.create_write_stream), each table has a default stream that can be written to. Google's explanation:

> Additionally, every table has a special stream named ‘_default’ to
> which data can be written. This stream doesn’t need to be created
> using CreateWriteStream. It is a stream that can be used
> simultaneously by any number of clients. Data written to this stream
> is considered committed as soon as an acknowledgement is received.

I am wondering how to access this "_default" stream and write to it using the Python client?

I tried the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1

write_client = bigquery_storage_v1.BigQueryWriteClient()
stream_name = "projects/{projectId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables/{tableName}/streams/_default"
stream = write_client.get_write_stream(name=stream_name)
```

But was met with the error: `NotFound: 404 Requested entity was not found`

---

**EDIT 2022-02-24:**

It turns out you cannot GET the _default stream using the client code in my example above. However, you can write to the _default stream using the name format `projects/{projectId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables/{tableName}/_default`

Comment: Actually found a reference to this stream name [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#appendrowsrequest). It suggests the convention is `projects/{project}/datasets/{dataset}/tables/{table}/_default` but this still gives me the same error

Comment: I presume you're using this as format string: `stream_name = f"projects/{projectId}/..."`, not `stream_name = "projects/{projectId}/..."` ?

Comment: Could you test by hardcoding `stream_name` to something like this: `projects/test-project/datasets/test-dataset/tables/test-table/_default` and see if it works?

Comment: You should be able to use `stream_name = 'projects/project-name/datasets/ds-name/tables/table-name/streams/_default'` to write the objects but it seams not work with the `get_write_stream` function. Try just write with it where `write_stream` apears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you cannot GET the _default stream using the client code in my example above. However, you can write to the _default stream using the name format `projects/{projectId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables/{tableName}/_default`

Answer (score 0):

projects/{projectId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables/{tableName}/streams/_default should work now.

It is recommended to use this sample to do your write:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-streaming